# Inaccessible Cardinals and Grothendieck Universes

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I'm trying to prove that the following statements are equivalent:

1.$\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{ON}\ \exists\ \kappa>\alpha$ is an inaccessible cardinal.

2.$\forall x\ \exists\ U\ x\in U$ and $U$ is a Grothendieck universe.

(1) $\rightarrow$ (2) is pretty straightforward. For the other direction, I was thinking to use induction on the ordinals; the successor case slides right by, but I have no ideas for the limit ordinals. Any thoughts are appreciated! Please let me know if definitions are required.

Comment: I think the proof is more or less like Zermelo theorem that states that in second order set theory every model is of the form $V_{\kappa}$ for $\kappa$ strongly inaccessible.

Comment: It suffices to show that $\left| U \right| = U \cap \mathbf{On}$ is an inaccessible cardinal for every Grothendieck universe $U$.

Comment: As a reference, I would suggest N.H. Williams, _On Grothendieck Universes_, Compositio Mathematica, tome 21, no. 1 (1969).